# make server to receieve/send data from/to a client several times(morethan once) in C

Tags: c

I have made a client and server application. In that when ever i am sending data to the server,the server is receiving data,but the server goes into the block state(waits to `recv` data still when data sending has been completed from client) then I compulsory needs to shutdown the socket form sending data. Which I don't want.

So can any one please tell me how to tell the server that my data transfer is completed.

My server behaves as following:

> CLIENT: hi //now compulsory to shutdown the socket otherwise server
>   goes into block state 
>   SERVER: hi //after this nothing can be
>   transferred since socket is closed

Where as i want like following:

> CLIENT: hi
>   SERVER: hi
>   CLIENT: how are you?
>   SERVER: I am fine, thanks! 
>   SERVER: What about you?
>   CLIENT: I am fine as well, thanks.

Comment: remove the fork() call in line#42.

Comment: which protocol are u using UDP, TCP, SCTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than setting the socket to be non-blocking, if that makes it easier, you need to develop your own protocol. This protocol would define the communications between client/server. For example, you could include data size, data, or just some form of data separator if you only use strings.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [ioctlsocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (on Windows) or the [fcntl](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html) function (in linux), and in particular, set the socket to be non-blocking.

```
fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Alternatively, have a separate thread to write to the socket while the first is blocking on the read.

Some more info here: http://rhoden.id.au/doc/sockets2.html

Comment: after setting the socket to non blocking mode the socket is returning SOCKET_ERROR which is leading to problem for me....

Comment: @Subrat nayak. I think you need to look at threading. The docs on those functions will tell you that it returns an error (usually something like E_WOULDBLOCK) and in that case you can just read again (you probably want to sleep a little bit, so you don't spinlock).